Girl contacts another girl in a different dimension
I watched a movie, it was released late 2013 - beginning of 2014.
I'm not sure about the plot, but I will try.
The movie is about a girl who found something in her room, and she could contact another girl from other dimension or something like that, where she was killed by her father. 
This main character, tries to save the girl. Then she finds out that her dad is going to kill her, and the story is a loop story, that happens in the house she is living in.
I remember the last scene of the movie, there was a fog, and every dead girl came to life, and took their vengeance on the murderer.

Possibly Haunter (2013) with Abigail Breslin, which combines a ghost story with a time loop. From Wiki:

Lisa Johnson, the ghost of a teenage girl who becomes aware that she is dead, haunts a house somewhere in northern Ontario. Along with her parents and brother, who are unaware that they are dead, she is stuck on the same day they were murdered in 1985. As she becomes more aware of her circumstances, she realizes that she can make contact with people in other timelines. As she explores this ability, a pale man appears and warns her to stop. Undeterred, Lisa uses personal items from other people killed in the house to make a connection with Olivia, part of a family living in the house in the future who will become the next set of victims. With the help of Olivia and the spirits of other murdered girls, Lisa is transported into the timelines of other victims and unravels the mystery of the house.

Olivia's father is possessed by the ghost of a serial killer who lived there. I thought of The Caller at first, but it's from 2011 and some things don't fit. Here's Haunter's trailer:




Yes, this is the movie I want, Thanks a lot, I was searching for the name for a while. I really appreciate it
